# Sistema de permissões em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

A muito tempo desenvolvi um sistema, em ASP.NET MVC, onde usei o pacote MvcSiteMapProvider, com base nele fiz algumas modificações no AuthorizeAttribute para realizar a verificação das permissões do usuário.

No meu SiteMap fiz algumas adições, que foram as Visibilidades

0 - para Centro de Trabalho (Básicamente as áreas do sistema),

1 - para visões (Basicamente meus controllers),

2 - para operações (Actions) e

3 - para não exibir.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Cidade" area="GRC" controller="Cidade" action="Index" visibilidade="1" key="5fdb0d96-1a21-4395-8868-e71c0ae061ec" >
                <mvcSiteMapNode title="Pesquisar" area="GRC" controller="Cidade" action="Index" visibilidade="2"  key="34d42538-d4cc-4091-a9cf-ab8b35326f62" />
                <mvcSiteMapNode title="Selecionar" area="GRC" controller="Cidade" action="Selecionar" visibilidade="3"  key="4146ff62-901f-4852-9084-a9c8434fc279" />
                <mvcSiteMapNode title="Inserir" area="GRC" controller="Cidade" action="Inserir" visibilidade="2"  key="02383e88-278b-4433-9960-b810866add30" />
                <mvcSiteMapNode title="Editar" area="GRC" controller="Cidade" action="Editar" visibilidade="3"  key="e5a58df4-4af8-428b-83d9-36e52a9f5ab3" />
                <mvcSiteMapNode title="Excluir" area="GRC" controller="Cidade" action="Excluir" visibilidade="3"  key="894c9fcf-8445-49dc-adac-bc6bde3b2986" />
            </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Bom base nessa visibilidade eu montava dinamicamente meus menus superior, lateral e ações de uma tela específica, basicamente tendo três PartialViews e uma classe para buscar no banco de dados os menus que o usuário tem permissão

_MenuCentroTrabalho

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Menu/superfish.css")" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Menu/superfish-vertical.css")" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Menu/hoverIntent.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Menu/superfish.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // initialise plugins
        $(function () {

        });
    });
</script>
<div class="clear">
    @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
</div>
<div id="menu2">
    <ul class="sf-menu" id="centrotrabalho">

        @using Syns.MvcApplication.WebSite
        @{
            var keyCentroTrabalho = MySiteMap.GetKeyCentroTrabalho((MvcSiteMapProvider.MvcSiteMapNode)SiteMap.CurrentNode);
        }

        @foreach (var item in MySiteMap.CentroTrabalho())
        {
            if (keyCentroTrabalho == item.Key)
            {
            <li class="current" style="background-color: Silver;">@Html.ActionLink(@item.Title, @item.Action, @item.Controller, new { Area = @item.Area }, null)</li>         
            }
            else
            { 
            <li class="current">@Html.ActionLink(@item.Title, @item.Action, @item.Controller, new { Area = @item.Area }, null)</li>         
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

_MenuOperacoes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // initialise plugins
        $(function () {

        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    @using Syns.MvcApplication.WebSite
    @{
        var operacoes = MySiteMap.Operacoes();
    }
    @foreach (var item in operacoes)
    {
        if (SiteMap.CurrentNode.Key == item.Key)
        {
        <div style="margin-right: 5px; float: left;">
            @item.Title
        </div>
        }
        else
        {
        <div style="margin-right: 5px; float: left;">
            @Html.ActionLink(@item.Title, @item.Action, @item.Controller, new { Area = @item.Area }, null)
        </div>
        }
        if (operacoes.Last().Key != item.Key)
        {
        <div style="margin-right: 5px; float: left;">
            |
        </div>
        }

    }
</div>
```

_MenuVisoes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="menu2">
    <ul class="sf-menu sf-vertical sf-js-enabled" id="visoes">
        @using Syns.MvcApplication.WebSite
        @{
            string visaoKey = MySiteMap.GetKeyVisao((MvcSiteMapProvider.MvcSiteMapNode)SiteMap.CurrentNode);
        }
        @foreach (var item in MySiteMap.Visoes())
        {
            if (visaoKey == item.Key)
            {
            <li class="current" style="background-color: Silver;">@Html.ActionLink(@item.Title, @item.Action, @item.Controller, new { Area = @item.Area }, null)</li>         
            }
            else
            { 
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(@item.Title, @item.Action, @item.Controller, new { Area = @item.Area }, null)</li>         
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

MySiteMap

```
public static class MySiteMap
    {
        public static List<SiteMapModel> Menus()
        {
            List<SiteMapModel> menus = new List<SiteMapModel>();

            try
            {

                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Menus"] != null)
                    menus = (List<SiteMapModel>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Menus"];
                else
                {
                    SiteMapServiceClient siteMapService = new SiteMapServiceClient();

                    if (UsuarioLogin != null)
                    {
                        UsuarioEntity usuario = new UsuarioBusiness().FindById(UsuarioLogin.UsuarioId);

                        menus = siteMapService.Menus(UsuarioLogin.UsuarioId);

                        if (menus.Count > 0)
                            HttpContext.Current.Session["Menus"] = menus;
                        else HttpContext.Current.Session["Menus"] = null;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new SynsException(ex.Message, 0, ex);
            }

            return menus;
        }

        public static List<SiteMapModel> CentroTrabalho()
        {
            var menus = Menus().Where(a => a.Visibilidade == 0 && a.Parent.HasValue);

            List<SiteMapModel> itens = new List<SiteMapModel>();

            if (menus.Count() > 0)
            {
                itens = menus.ToList();
            }

            return itens;
        }

        public static List<SiteMapModel> Visoes()
        {
            string keyCentroTrabalho = GetKeyCentroTrabalho((MvcSiteMapNode)SiteMap.CurrentNode);

            var menus = Menus().Where(a => a.Visibilidade == 1 && a.KeyParent == keyCentroTrabalho);

            List<SiteMapModel> itens = new List<SiteMapModel>();

            if (menus.Count() > 0)
            {
                itens = menus.ToList();
            }

            return itens;
        }

        public static List<SiteMapModel> Operacoes()
        {
            string keyVisao = GetKeyVisao((MvcSiteMapNode)SiteMap.CurrentNode);

            var menus = Menus().Where(a => a.Visibilidade == 2 && a.KeyParent == keyVisao);

            List<SiteMapModel> itens = new List<SiteMapModel>();

            if (menus.Count() > 0)
            {
                itens = menus.ToList();
            }

            return itens;
        }



        public static string GetKeyVisao(MvcSiteMapNode node)
        {
            if (node == null)
                return "";

            if (node.Visibilidade != "1")
                return GetKeyVisao((MvcSiteMapNode)node.ParentNode);

            return node.Key;
        }

        public static string GetKeyCentroTrabalho(MvcSiteMapNode node)
        {
            if (node == null)
                return "";

            if (node.Visibilidade != "0")
                return GetKeyCentroTrabalho((MvcSiteMapNode)node.ParentNode);

            return node.Key;
        }


        private static UsuarioLoginEntity UsuarioLogin
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session.Count > 0
                    && HttpContext.Current.Session["Usuario"] != null
                    && HttpContext.Current.Session["Usuario"] is UsuarioLoginEntity)
                {
                    var temp = (UsuarioLoginEntity)HttpContext.Current.Session["Usuario"];

                    return temp;
                }


                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Mesmo retornando somente os menus que o usuário tinha permissão, eu fazia mais uma verificação usando o AuthorizaAttribute.

MyAuthorize

```
public class MyAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public MyAuthorize()
        {

        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext != null &&
                filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Count > 0 &&
                filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Usuario"] != null &&
                filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Usuario"] is UsuarioLoginEntity)
            {
                var temp = (UsuarioLoginEntity)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Usuario"];

                var usuario = new UsuarioBusiness().FindById(temp.UsuarioId);
                if (usuario.MudarSenhaProximoLogin == true)
                    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.Contains("Usuario/MudarSenha") && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.Contains("Usuario/Sair"))
                    {
                        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/HCM/Usuario/MudarSenha");
                    }
            }

            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext != null &&
                httpContext.Session.Count > 0 &&
                httpContext.Session["Usuario"] != null &&
                httpContext.Session["Usuario"] is UsuarioLoginEntity)
            {
                var temp = (UsuarioLoginEntity)httpContext.Session["Usuario"];

                if (temp == null)
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();


                return VerificaPermissao(temp.UsuarioId);
            }

            return false;
        }

        private bool VerificaPermissao(int usuarioId)
        {
            //var siteMapKey = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Key;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Isso funciona bem, porém agora que estou realizando o curso de [ASP.NET MVC Módulo 1](http://codingcraft.com.br/2016/05/30/coding-craft-asp-net-mvc-e-asp-net-web-api-modulo-1/), oferecido pelo Cigano, estou estudando sobre o ASP.NET Identity e com ele surgiram alguns detalhes novos, como o uso do Claims.

Então passei a me questionar, se existiria uma forma de readaptar o meu cenário com Claims?

Todo esse sistema de permissão surgiu pelo fato de o sistema usado na época já ser assim. Onde os usuários tinham suas permissões baseados em menus e ações (CRUD) que podiam ou não realizar. Esse sistema era um aplicativo Windows.

Então passei a me questionar também, se para sistemas mais complexos desenvolvidos em ASP.NET Mvc, se devo repensar o meu conceito de permissão?

Surgindo assim a questão, como criar um sistema de permissão de usuário, onde o “Usuário A” tenha permissão de cadastrar clientes, o “Usuário B” tenha permissão de cadastrar e editar clientes, o “Usuário C” tenha permissão de cadastra, editar e excluir clientes, o “Usuário ...” tenha permissão de somente visualizar os clientes.

Consigo fazer isso com Claims, ou estou com meu conceito sobre o que posso fazer com Claims errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Consigo fazer isso com Claims, ou estou com meu conceito sobre o que posso fazer com Claims errado?

Em resumo, sim. Vamos supor o seguinte atributo de autorização:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string claimType;
    private string claimValue;
    public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string type, string value)
    {
        this.claimType = type;
        this.claimValue = value;
    }
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        if (user != null && user.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

E suponha a seguinte decoração:

```
[ClaimsAuthorize("NivelTecnico", "Coordenador")]
```

O que fazemos aqui é verificar se o usuário corrente é um coordenador ou não. Se for, ele deve ter permissões no elemento decorado.

Comment: Com base na sua resposta, eu teria que ter uma lista definida dos Claims e de forma que eu fiz, não tenho papéis e nem atribuições definidas, minhas permissões são diretamente baseadas no usuário com a action.
Tento que decoro meu controller só com [MyAuthorize] sem definir as Roles

Comment: Esta abordagem não permite uma parametrização, o que pode representar alguma penalidade, sobretudo no exemplo que apresentei.