# MVC - Armazenar permissões do usuário em sessão usando NLB - Balanceamento de Carga em Rede

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estamos desenvolvendo uma aplicação (intranet) em MVC 4 onde a autenticação é realizada através de Windows Authentication.

Quando o usuário entra na aplicação, é realizada uma chamada a um serviço que controla as permissões do usuário naquele módulo, onde são recuperados neste momento todas as telas e funcionalidades que o usuário pode acessar.

No primeiro momento, estamos armazenando estas informações de permissão do usuário na sessão, pois sempre que uma ação é executada no controlador temos que validar se o usuário realmente possui permissão para realizar tal tarefa.

O problema é que agora descobrimos que o servidor de produção será configurado com NLB (Balanceamento de carga), ou seja, nada garante que as próximas requisições do usuário serão realizadas no mesmo servidor, o que pode invalidar a sessão do mesmo.

Existem algumas configurações que podem ser realizadas no NLB que tratam essa questão da sessão, mas pelo que andei lendo não é muito recomendada pois "quebra" a escalabilidade da aplicação.

Alguém conhece alguma outra forma onde poderia armazenar estes dados ou uma alternativa a esta solução?

Obrigado!

Comment: Não use sessões para autenticação quando você precisa de load balancer. Tente alguma abordagem alternativa, como o próprio banco de dados ou autenticação baseada em cookies.

Comment: Você tem algum exemplo de autenticação baseada em cookies? O usuário não consegue manipular os dados, já que são gravados no cliente?

Comment: Na verdade a autenticação já é feita. Preciso saber como persistir estas informações me cookie de forma segura.

Comment: Banco de dados.

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada nessa minha pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139539/sistema-de-permiss%C3%B5es-em-asp-net-mvc pode ser uma alternativa para você

Answer (score 0):

Se é realmente necessário usar sessões para preservar as permissões do usuário, [você pode usar um **StateServer** ou um **SQLServer**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx). A configuração da aplicação é feita da seguinte forma:

## StateServer

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <sessionState mode="StateServer"
      stateConnectionString="tcpip=Teste:42424"
      cookieless="false"
      timeout="20"/>
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

## SQLServer

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
      sqlConnectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;data 
        source=TesteSqlServer;" />
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

[Os passos para configuração de um **StateServer** estão aqui](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c26fe862-04b5-4aae-a8b9-fe0e742a99c6).

Se não é necessário usar sessões, [um atributo de autorização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140225/2999) pode ser uma ótima alternativa.